# Enterprise Library 3.1 Rolling Flat File Listener Issue

Tags: c#, enterprise-library

**UPDATE 4/14/2011:
In speaking with Enterprise Library support in version 4.1 there had been an addition to fix the problem with the rolling flat file trace listener when using impersonation. Well I am using impersonation for my web service but I'm using Enterprise Library 3.1:**

**Taken from the documentation of EntLib
4.1 (Changes in the Logging Application Block)**

> "Added: Configuration support to
>   opt-out of the impersonation-reverting
>   default setting has been added. This
>   fixes the rolling flat file trace
>   listener problem when used in a Web
>   application and when impersonation is
>   enabled. To opt-out of the
>   impersonation-reverting default mode,
>   set the new 
>   revertImpersonation attribute to
>   false. The default setting is true.
>   This supports configuration support,
>   design time support, and manageability
>   support (both WMI and group policy)."

**==============================================================================**

Currently I have a WCF web service logging all calls to its method parameters. When ever there is heavy traffic on the web service the logging stops completely and I get the following error while rolling to a new log file. The heavy traffic is to be expected The error details has been given below.

**Configuration:
WCF Web service running in Windows Server 2008 IIS 7.5
Using Enterprise Library 3.1 to do logging.**

> Error Error: 6352 : Timestamp:
>   4/8/2011 11:30:45 PM Message: Tracing
>   to LogSource 'Trace' failed.
>   Processing for other sources will
>   continue. See summary information
>   below for more information. Should
>   this problem persist, stop the service
>   and check the configuration file(s)
>   for possible error(s) in the
>   configuration of the categories and
>   sinks.
>
> Summary for Enterprise Library
>   Distributor Service:
>
> ==========================================
>
> Exception Information Details:
>   ====================================== Exception Type:
>   System.NullReferenceException Message:
>   Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object. Data:
>   System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>   TargetSite: Void
>   PerformRoll(System.DateTime) HelpLink:
>   NULL Source:
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging
>
> StackTrace Information Details: 
>   ======================================    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener.StreamWriterRollingHelper.PerformRoll(DateTime
>   rollDateTime)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener.StreamWriterRollingHelper.RollIfNecessary()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener.TraceData(TraceEventCache
>   eventCache, String source,
>   TraceEventType eventType, Int32 id,
>   Object data)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogSource.TraceData(TraceEventType
>   eventType, Int32 id, LogEntry
>   logEntry, TraceListenerFilter
>   traceListenerFilter)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.ProcessLog(LogEntry
>   log)

**Part of the config. I have 5 logs error.log, general.log, trace.log, params.log, performance.log all the configs look like this.**

```
<add fileName="D:\Logs\trace.log" rollSizeKB="1000" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd" 
rollFileExistsBehavior="Increment" rollInterval="Day" formatter="Text Formatter" 
header="----------------------------------------"
footer="----------------------------------------" 
listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
traceOutputOptions="None" 
type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
name="Rolling Flat-File Listener" />
```

Comment: Can you post the configuration?

Comment: Here is part of the config. Like I mentioned, this only happens when there is heavy traffic on the web service. I'm currently logging heavily in the trace.log perhaps I need to move some logging to the other logs.